# Could 94-HB board be used for SMD and THT soldering?

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, pcb-assembly, materials, production

I have a circuit that I designed lately which is quite simple based on just 1 opamp and have an SMD and THT components (like a relay) and will be producing mass production in Chinese factories and it is more price depending than quality, so could 94-HB board be coated with OSP and be used to be SMD and THT assembled?

Specs:

Layer: 1 Layer

Board type: 94-HB

board thickness is: 1.00 mm

Solder mask: only at the bottom is green solder mask

coating: OSP

thickness: 1.00 mm